# Why is this getting NullPointerException & ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException errors

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Getting a `NullPointerError` on line 24 (second for loop) and an `arrayoutofindexexception` on the main method. I have no idea how to solve this and an explanation would be much appreciated. Please help!

Edit: 'NullPointerError' solved, just needed to initialize the ArrayList for it, but still can't work out the 'ArrayOutOfIndexException' error.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SnackBar
{
    private Random randomizer;
    private String[] flavours;
    private SnackMachine barMachine;
    ArrayList<Student> students;

    public SnackBar(int numStudents, int packetsBarMachine, int costPacket)
    {
        randomizer = new Random();
        flavours = new String[] {"prawn cocktail", "tango cheese", "natural", "paprika", "salt and vinegar"};
        barMachine = new SnackMachine(packetsBarMachine, costPacket);
 students = new ArrayList<Student>();

        for(int i = 0; i < packetsBarMachine; i++)
        {
            barMachine.addPack(new PackOfCrisps(randomFlavour()));
            i++;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < numStudents; j++)
        {
            students.add(new Student(randomFlavour(), barMachine));            
            j++;
        }
    }

    public String randomFlavour()
    {
        int random = randomizer.nextInt(flavours.length);
        return flavours[random];
    }

    public void describe()
    {
        System.out.println("The SnackBar has " + students.size() + " hungry students.");
        System.out.println("The Snackmachine has:");
        System.out.println(barMachine.countPacks("prawn cocktail") + " packets of prawn cocktail crisps,");
        System.out.println(barMachine.countPacks("tango cheese") + " packets of tango cheese crisps,");
        System.out.println(barMachine.countPacks("natural") + " packets of natural crisps,");
        System.out.println(barMachine.countPacks("paprika") + " packets of paprika crisps,");
        System.out.println(barMachine.countPacks("salt and vinegar") + " packets of salt and vinegar crisps.");
    }

    public void runSnackBar(int nSteps)
    {
        int step = 1;

        while(step <= nSteps)
        {
            System.out.println("Time Step " + step);
            describe();
            int atRandom = randomizer.nextInt(students.size());
            students.get(atRandom).snackTime();
            step++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SnackBar bar = new SnackBar (Integer.parseInt(args[4]), Integer.parseInt(args[20]), Integer.parseInt(args[5]));

        bar.runSnackBar(Integer.parseInt(args[30]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have realy 20 arguments for your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you should initialize the `ArrayList<Student> students` list.

`Integer.parseInt(args[30])` is also suspicious, since for that not to throw an exception, you have to supply 31 command line arguments. Same goes for all your other attempts to access elements of `args` array without checking its length first.

Comment: Ah yes, silly mistake there. Still getting the Arrayindexoutofbound error on the main method, however...

Comment: @ASCH did you see my edit?

Comment: Just saw it, thanks for pointing it out. How would you propose I go about it?

Comment: @ASCH always make sure `args.length > i` before accessing `args[i]`

Comment: Nvm, another silly mistake on my part. I needed to simply enter an integer instead of an arg. Thanks a lot for the help!